# MYSQL: after "start transaction" , "select *" return no record

Tags: php, mysql, select, transactions

Someone can explain why in this block of code, "select *" return no record? The table category has many records.

```
        $this->db->execute('START TRANSACTION;');

      $this->db->execute("
update ps_category c
left join products pa on (c.key = pa.id_product and pa.special)
set c.active = 0
where pa.id_product IS NULL and c.id_category >2 and c.id_category NOT IN(7,8)
            ");            
        
        $categories = $this->db->executeS("select * from ps_category"); //return 0 record
$this->db->execute('COMMIT;');
```

Instead moving the "start transaction" under the first "update" statement make the "select" return the actual records.  Why?

```
  $this->db->execute("
update ps_category c
left join products pa on (c.key = pa.id_product and pa.special)
set c.active = 0
where pa.id_product IS NULL and c.id_category >2 and c.id_category NOT IN(7,8)
            ");            

$this->db->execute('START TRANSACTION;');
        $categories = $this->db->executeS("select * from ps_category");//return the actual rows
$this->db->execute('COMMIT;');
```

EDIT: there is not other process that alter the table in the meanwhile. The only thing that was changed is the position of "start transaction"

Comment: and why didn't you commit your transcaction

Comment: @nbk
I have not reported the commit in the example but in the real code there is.

Comment: a) in your working version, you use "dbPrestashop", in the others you use "db" - is this just an oversight cleaning up your code for the question, or are you using different connections? b) "0" indicates an error, so check the mysql error message.

Comment: maybe [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2021/02/11/various-types-of-innodb-transaction-isolation-levels-explained-using-terminal/) can shed some light on this.

Comment: @Solarflare nope, that was an error in the example code ;), i've edited the question... thank you. In the code in production i only moved the line with "start transaction" from before to after the "update" statement